# Weapon not changing in terminal game c++

Tags: c++

I was trying to make a game in c++ but ran into a problem,
I have tried to fix it but with no good outcome,

*Main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Classes.h"


int main()
{
    using Game::Player;
    using std::cout; using std::cin; using std::endl;

    Player p1;
    Player p2;

    int turn = 1;

    while (p1.health > 0 && p2.health > 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "Player1 HP: " << p1.health << endl;
        cout << "Player2 HP: " << p2.health << endl;

        // p1's turn
        if (turn == 1)
        {
            cout << endl << "Player1's turn" << endl;
            cout << "Current weapon: " << p1.current_weapon << endl;
            cout << "Medkit count: " << p1.medkit_count << endl;
            cout << endl << "Enter A for ATTACK, H to HEAL, N for NEXT WEAPON: ";

            int dmg{};

            if (p1.current_weapon == (char*)p1.weapons[0])
            {
                dmg = p1.weapon_dmg[0];
            }
            else if (p1.current_weapon == (char*)p1.weapons[1])
            {
                dmg = p1.weapon_dmg[1];
            }
            else if (p1.current_weapon == (char*)p1.weapons[2])
            {
                dmg = p1.weapon_dmg[2];
            }

            char p1_Move;
            cin >> p1_Move;

            //Player 1 Attacks
            if (p1_Move == 'A')
            {
                p2.health -= dmg;
                if (p2.health <= 0)
                {
                    p2.health = 0;
                }
                turn = 2;
            }

            //Player 1 Uses Potion
            else if (p1_Move == 'H')
            {
                if (p1.medkit_count > 0)
                {
                    p1.health += p1.medkit_heal_amount;
                    p1.medkit_count--;
                    if (p1.health > p1.max_health)
                    {
                        p1.health = p1.max_health;
                    }
                    turn = 2;
                }
            }

            //Player 1 Switches weapon
            else if (p1_Move == 'N')
            {
                p1.nextWeapon(p1);
            }

            //Player 1 Skips
            else
            {
                turn = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (turn == 2)
        {
            cout << endl << "Player2's turn" << endl;
            cout << "Current weapon: " << p2.current_weapon << endl;
            cout << "Medkit count: " << p2.medkit_count << endl;
            cout << endl << "Enter A for ATTACK, H to HEAL, N for NEXT WEAPON: ";

            int dmg{};

            if (p2.current_weapon == (char*)p2.weapons[0])
            {
                dmg = p2.weapon_dmg[0];
            }
            else if (p2.current_weapon == (char*)p2.weapons[1])
            {
                dmg = p2.weapon_dmg[1];
            }
            else if (p2.current_weapon == (char*)p2.weapons[2])
            {
                dmg = p2.weapon_dmg[2];
            }

            char p2_Move;
            cin >> p2_Move;

            if (p2_Move == 'A')
            {
                p1.health -= dmg;
                if (p1.health <= 0)
                {
                    p1.health = 0;
                }
                turn = 1;
            }

            else if (p2_Move == 'H')
            {
                if (p2.medkit_count > 0)
                {
                    p2.health += p2.medkit_heal_amount;
                    p2.medkit_count--;
                    if (p2.health > p2.max_health)
                    {
                        p2.health = p2.max_health;
                    }
                    turn = 1;
                }
            }

            else if (p2_Move == 'N')
            {
                p1.nextWeapon(p1);

            }

            else
            {
                turn = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (p1.health <= 0 && p2.health > 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "PLAYER 2 WINS" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
    else if (p2.health <= 0 && p1.health > 0)
    {
        system("cls");
        cout << "PLAYER 1 WINS" << endl;
        system("pause");
    }
     

    return 0;
}
```

*Classes.h*

```
#pragma once

namespace Game
{

    class Player
    {
    public:
        int health = 10;
        int max_health = 10;

        int medkit_count = 3;
        int medkit_heal_amount = 4;

        const char* weapons[3] = {"Pistol", "Rifle", "Shovel"};
        int weapon_dmg[3] = {1, 3, 5};

        const char* default_weapon = weapons[0];
        char* current_weapon = (char*)default_weapon;

        void nextWeapon(Player plr)
        {
            if (plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[0])
            {
                plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[1];
            }
            else if (plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[1])
            {
                plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[2];
            }
            else if (plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[2])
            {
                plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[0];
            }
        }

        bool changing_weapon = false;
    };
}
```

when you press N to switch weapons it doesn't switch and stays the same, what could I do to fix this problem? The answer is probably obvious but i just cannot see it.

I'm new to c++ so go easy on me,
thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `nextWeapon` should take `plr` by reference

Comment: Why does the `nextWeapon` method receive another `Player` as argument and why do you call `p1.nextWeapon(p1)` also for player 2?

Comment: @AlanBirtles what do you mean by this? how could I implement that?

Comment: To summarise `p1.nextWeapon(p1);` should be `p1.nextWeapon();` and `void nextWeapon(Player plr)` should be `void nextWeapon()` and `if (plr.current_weapon == (char*)weapons[0])`should be `if (current_weapon == (char*)weapons[0])` etc. etc

Comment: Please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: You went down a deep rabbit hole. It would have been avoided if you had just asked yourself here `p1.nextWeapon(p1)` why do I need to mention `p1` twice? That should have felt wrong and warned you that you were doing something bad.

Comment: And remember when comparing `char*`, the `==` operator compares the *pointers*, not the strings contents. For strings, use `std::string` instead.

Comment: And almost every time (including here) when you feel the need to do a C-style cast (like `(char*)weapons[0]`) then you should take that as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @nbslay `nextWeapon` should **not** take `plr` by reference, `plr` should be removed entirely.

Comment: @john &Someprogrammerdude All of this made my code alot cleaner, thank you but i still have the problem?

Comment: @nbslay Would need to see the updated code. Try asking a new question. Hopefully it won;t get closed so quickly this time.

Comment: @john I edited it to show links to my updated working code! You and some other also helped me alot, so i wouldn't have been able to get it working without the help of you guys :D

Comment: Please don't edit answers/solutions into questions. Questions should only be questions.